# Laravel 5.2 use both paginate query and no paginate query

Tags: laravel-5

I am developing a project with laravel 5.2. I have a problem, In my PostController, I accept an argument `is_paginated`, it is an integer. If `0`, it means query all posts. If `1`, it means use pagination query. Besides this argument, I also accept many additional arguments, and according to their value I determine add constraints to query or not. For example, users can pass `add_time` to query posts generated on specific day. So in my controller, I now write:

```
public function getPosts(Request $request){
 $isPaginated = $request->input('is_paginates');
 if($isPaginated){
  /*
   *According to additional arguments to add query constraints or not, then 
   *use paginate method.
   */
   .....->paginate(10);
 }else{
  /*
   *According to additional arguments to add query constraints or not, then 
   *use get method.
   */
   ......->get();
 }
}
```

So you can see, I wrote `add constraints` code twice, and if there are many constraints to add, it looks very bloated. So are there other ways to get done this?

Comment: you have a typo on `$request->input('is_paginates');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wonders of method chaining here:

```
var $a = \App\Class::where("c",1);        
if($offset = $request->input("offset")){
    $a = $a->skip($offset);
}
if($limit = $request->input("limit")){
    $a = $a->take($limit);
}
if($request->input("is_paginated")){
    $a = $a->paginate(10);
}
$a_vals = $a->get();
```